# What to do when firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken() throws "auth/user-token-expired"?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

First, I didn't think this was possible.  The documentation states:

"Returns the current token if it has not expired. Otherwise, this will refresh the token and return a new one."

So in what case would it throw this error?  If the refresh token expired, than why wouldn't it instead refresh it?  What is the best way to recover from this?  Set a timer and try again?  Seems like an anti-pattern.

This doesn't happen often.  I've seen it on safari iPhone, especially when waking up a tab that was signed in anonymously.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the user session is revoked or disabled. Revocation happens during big account changes, eg. when the user updates their email or password in another session or the user sessions are revoked via the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens).

The error will be thrown and the user is signed out and deactivated. The expectation is to sign in again or re-authenticate the user.

Comment: Thanks!  So in this case it's anonymously signed in users, and on my backend I'm never revoking tokens manually.  Any other possibilities?   I guess I can just re-sign in anonymously behind the scenes, and do a merge of anything the anon user had done before this problem occured.

Comment: Did you delete the user via Admin SDK or Firebase Console? Try to inspect the network console to get more details on the server side error that is thrown.

Comment: I have not deleted any users via either.  I wish I could reproduce this issue.  One time it happened to me when I opened safari iOS and an existing tab revived -- suddenly the error was thrown.  Thanks for the network console tip when it happens next.  Annoyingly on iOS I have to connect a device to a mac and use safari remote debugging.